# Jquery defining id with a variable

Tags: jquery

So this works fine, as you all know

```
$("#foo").html = "bar";
```

But how would I do this?

```
var i = "foo";
$(i).html= "bar";
```

I've tried `$("#"+i)` as well, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work.

```
$("#foo").html = "bar"; //Overwrites the object's html function with a string
```

This should.

```
$("#"+i).html("bar"); //Sets the inner HTML of the selected element.
```

Comment: Yep, you're right, I needed the brackets not the `=`.  I'm getting the two mixed up.  Silly mistake.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i don't know what are you tring to do

but if you want to insert this value `bar` in the `id='foo'`

you can use

```
   var i = "foo" ;

   $('#'+i).html("bar");
```